# Does using Proguard to obfuscate my app keep my server key safe/secure?

Tags: java, android, firebase, security, proguard

I used proguard to obfuscate my code and I believed this is useful to avoid APK decompile, and I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging and I need to put my FIREBASE SERVER KEY inside my code, including API key etc. User has the authenthication by signing up or login and I'm using JAVA.

My concern is, Is it safe to put my SERVER KEY in my code? If its not safe, can you help me to secure my KEY? any tutorial?

Edited: I am using chat app and I need the server key for Notification Firebase Cloud Messaging

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not safe, and there is no way for you to safely store that type of key in your app.  You should not put your **server** key in the app at all—that's why it's called a server key.

A sufficiently determined attacker can always reverse engineer your app, no matter how thoroughly obfuscated it is.  The only way to safely manage a server key is to store it on your server and manage access to the data through the code on the server.  The exact means of doing this will vary and depend on the exact details of each application.

For Firebase specifically, you should look at [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules), which may allow you to manage access to data without the need for a server key.

Comment: #Ryan M Im creating a chat app, and everthing works fine, but my concern is security for my server key